# How to remove $(Configuration) at Additional Library Directory in Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I generated a Visual Studio solution using CMake.

However, the useless postfix `$(Configuration)` is attached at **Additional Library Directories** like below:

```
C:/_intermediate/packages/opencv-3.2/lib/$(Configuration); 
C:/_intermediate/packages/opencv-3.2/lib/$(Configuration)/$(Configuration)
```

Why is this, and how can I remove that?

```
include_directories("C:/_intermediate/packages/opencv-3.2/include")
link_directories("C:/_intermediate/packages/opencv-3.2/lib/$(Configuration)")
```

Comment: Why do you add the postfix manually in the `link_directories()` call? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Doesn't `CMake` already support `opencv` with `find_package(opencv REQUIRED)` as in this example [https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html)

Comment: I have used several libraries including OpenCV. Some libraries are not located in $(Configuration) folder. So I added the root folder as the library directory.